# Have a form to edit user account, make default values current values but still use v-model?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a form to edit your user account in Vue/Laravel.

Ideally I'd like to make the name and email boxes pre-filled with the users current values. I could do that easily using

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" autocomplete="false" :value="$parent.user.name">
```

The issue is that I'd also like to use `v-model="form.name"` like so:

```
<template>
    <form class="row" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" autocomplete="false" :value="$parent.user.name" v-model="form.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="false" name="email" :value="$parent.user.email" v-model="form.email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" name="password" v-model="form.password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>



<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
            })
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            // ajax stuff here
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But this throws an error **:value="$parent.user.name" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally** which I think I understand as it can't be two models.

Is there a better way to go about getting a form filled with values already, but bind it to some sort of model so I can easily submit the form with axios? (I'm trying to use the Form class from the Vue Laracast tutorial but not sure if there's a better method of doing all of this.) https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms/blob/master/public/js/app.js

It appears I can access `$parent.user.name` in the template part, but can't use `this.$parent.user.name` in the script part of the file.

This is all in a route Vue file if that makes any difference. Here is my main vue app.

```
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import AuthUser from './models/AuthUser';

new Vue({

el: '#app',
components: {
    Nav
},

data() {
    return {
        user: []
    }
},

created() {
    AuthUser.load(user => this.user = user);
},

router
});
```

Comment: It's bad practice to access data using `$parent`. Use props instead.

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` already binds the value, so you can't bind the `value` to one thing and `v-model` to something else.

To start with the desired values, you can do this:

```
data() {
    return {
        form: new Form({
            name: this.$parent.user.name,
            email: this.$parent.user.email,
            password: this.$parent.user.password, //please don't, it's just an example :)
        })
    }
},
```

And remove `:value` from the elements:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" autocomplete="false" v-model="form.name">
```

Comment: Oddly when I tried this I just get blank input fields. Vue DevTools shows that form name is undefined. But I can use $parent.user.name in my template part of the file, but this.$parent.user.name is undefined when I try to use it in the script part.

Comment: Where does `$parent` come from? What version of Vue is that?

Comment: Looks like I'm using 2.5.7 according to the package.json. I was just using $parent from someones recommendation on how to access parent data inside components/routes. On the main Vue app I have data that returns the current user from an ajax call.

Comment: Oh god please no. Don't try to access parent data from a component. Use [props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) instead.

Comment: Is it possible to add props to routes? Would I just pass those in the routes file? I'm not calling this file anywhere as a component.

Comment: Oh man in this case I think you should look into Vuex or Event Bus.

Comment: Okay, looking into Vuex now. Thank you!

Comment: @Octoxan you can [pass props to routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html).